# Is it precise to say a ring is an algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

For example, when we say that every ring $R$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra with the homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{Z} \to R$  sending $n \mapsto n \cdot 1_R$, what exactly does it mean for 'a ring to be an algebra'? A ring is a ring; but an algebra is a ring with a structure map. What is the benefit or insight gained from equating $R$ with a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra? Are there other such examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algebra is full of structures which are "things over things."

For groups, we talk about group actions, which are just "sets over a group." A group action can be described two equivalent ways. For a group $G$ acting on a set $X$, we sometimes call $X$ a $G$-set. This can be defined two equivalent ways:

1. There exists a map $G\times X\to X$, written $(g,x)\mapsto g\cdot x$, satisfying the properties $1\cdot x=x$, $(gh)\cdot x=g\cdot (h\cdot x)$
2. There exists a homomorphism $G\to \operatorname{Aut}(X)$, where $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is the group of permutations of $X$.

Next, we encounter modules, which are "abelian groups over a ring." An $R$-module $M$ can be defined as

1. An abelian group $M$ along with an action $R\times M\to M$ satisfying $1\cdot x=x$, $r\cdot(x+y)=r\cdot x+r\cdot y$, $(r+s)\cdot x=r\cdot x+s\cdot x$, and $(rs)\cdot x=r\cdot (s\cdot x)$
2. An abelian group $M$ along with a ring homomorphism $R\to \operatorname{End}(M)$, where $\operatorname{End}(M)$ is the group of maps $M\to M$.

Then we have algebras, which are like "rings over a ring." An $R$-algebra $A$ can be defined as

1. An $R$-module $A$, where $A$ is also a ring, and the action of $R$ is required to commute with the multiplication in $A$. That is, we have a map $R\times A\to A$ satisfying $(r\cdot a)(s\cdot b)=rs\cdot ab$.
2. A ring $A$ together with a ring homomorphism $R\to Z(A)$, where $Z(A)$ is the center of $A$.

---

I'm mentioning all these things because I am procrastinating, but also because it helped me a lot to realize how analogous these things are.

In the category of rings, $\Bbb Z$ is an initial object. If you don't know categories, all this means is that, for any ring $R$, there is a unique map $\Bbb Z\to R$. Now, since $\Bbb Z$ is a commutative ring, we see that the image of this map must be in the center of $R$, and so this map makes any ring $R$ into a $\Bbb Z$-algebra. Conversely, given a $\Bbb Z$-algebra $R$, by definition, $R$ is a ring.

There is one important note here, though: the use of the word "algebra" is not standard. Some people assume "algebra" to mean "algebra over a field." In this case, every algebra is a ring, but not every ring is an algebra. Also, some authors talk about non-unital or non-associative algebras. Usually a ring is assumed to be unital and associative, so in this case, algebras and rings are incomparable.

---

If you are confused about these statements, it is a good exercise to just prove them. For example, consider the two definitions I gave for (unital associative) $R$-algebras. Given such a map $R\times A\to A$, note that for each $r\in R$, we have a corresponding map $A\to A$. But this is determined just by where it sends $1$. This gives us a way to define a map $R\to A$. You can also show that the image is necessarily central. Conversely, start with a ring homomorphism $R\to Z(A)$ and try to define an $R$-algebra structure on $A$ with the first definition.

Answer (score 0):

When we say that every ring "is" a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, what we mean precisely is that there is an [equivalence of categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories) between the category of rings and the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras (given by forgetting the structure map). The word "is" is doing a lot of work here, and really people typically mean not only that there is such an equivalence but that a particular map they have in mind produces it.

This equivalence can be thought of as coming from a more basic equivalence between abelian groups and $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (we get rings resp. $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras by taking [monoid objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory)) with respect to the tensor product), and one practical upshot is that it reminds you that [extension of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings) functors are available: if $f : R \to S$ is any ring homomorphism, it induces an extension of scalars functor $(-) \otimes_R S$ from $R$-modules to $S$-modules, and if $R$ and $S$ are both commutative this functor also sends $R$-algebras to $S$-algebras.

Comment: "Is" also sometimes refers to a fully faithful functor rather than an equivalence, e.g. every abelian group "is" a group. Properly we should at least say "rings are precisely $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras" to refer to equivalences.

Comment: Do you have a reference for a precise statement + proof of this equivalence of categories?

Comment: @D.Zack: it is a very easy exercise, just write down all the definitions. The point is that every ring has a unique $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra structure.

Comment: Oh I agree that it's easy to see that these are the same! What I'm looking for is the actual functor that witnesses this equivalence, and e.g. why it's fully faithful and essentially surjective.

(I'd hope for something that could be adapted to some equivalence of infinity categories of simplicial algebras)

Comment: The functor just forgets the $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure. I don't understand why you say that it's "easy to see that these are the same" but you don't understand why this functor is fully faithful and essentially surjective. The corresponding statement for $E_{\infty}$ ring spectra is false unless $\mathbb{Z}$ is replaced by the sphere spectrum. The point in both cases is that $\mathbb{Z}$ is the initial commutative ring and the sphere spectrum is the initial $E_{\infty}$ ring spectrum so there's no choice about what the action map is.

Comment: Maybe not worth dragging out in comments -- my issue is that "there is an equivalence of categories" elides subtle qualifiers. E.g. perhaps you implicitly mean unital commutative rings and unital associative commutative $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras, no...? And is your category of $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras (1) $\mathbb{Z}$-modules with a bilinear product, or (2) rings admitting a map $\mathbb{Z}\to Z(R)$? These aren't clearly equivalent categories for noncommutative nonassociative algebras..

(These are of course minor details, hence my original question about a reference for a precise statement!)

Comment: Of course I mean unital associative $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras or else the statement is wildly false. My convention is that "algebra" always implies unital and associative by default and I think the other convention is very bad.

Comment: Right! Precisely my point. But "of course" is doing a lot of work here: this context is obvious if you're in an elementary commutative algebra course, perhaps less so for those looking at Lie or Poisson or C^* or convolution algebras where some of these assumptions are dropped. But again, the real question was just about a citable source.